# Xcode-style placeholders in an NSTextView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstextview

In Xcode, if you type `<# Hello, Word #>` into the text editor, it automatically gets converted to a pale-blue pill-shaped placeholder, but on disk, the text remains exactly as it was typed. Does anyone know if the same effect is achievable using `NSTextView`? I've got some very ugly filepaths that must remain exactly as they are so `sphinx` can put together my docs, but I want to present the user with something a little more attractive when they view the file in my custom text editor.

```
// This on disk (and in any other text editor)
.. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf.png

// This shown to the user in my custom text editor
Image of a golden eagle
```

Comment: Is that __Image__ clickable or just a colored?

Comment: Ideally I guess it would be clickable (perhaps to show a QuickLook of the .png being referenced), but the critical aspect is that, regardless of what the user sees, the file on the filesystem contains the actual link.

Comment: I've checked the answer and accepted it. I should apologize however for not responding more promptly - I didn't realize bounties were time-limited, so I think you only get 25 points. Have contacted SO to see if they'll grant a bit of leeway so you can get the full 50.

Comment: No please all just fine, just I wonder if it did work or not. Honestly I was no intention to ask for acceptance or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As much as possible tried to write explanations as a comment in code. What I have done here.

1. Found all matched links `.. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf1.png` with Regex and add them into an array.
2. Replaced all matched links `.. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf1.png` with **[Image]** string
3. Found all [Image] strings and formatted with NSMutableAttributedString as a link.

It does what you are asking and it does on the fly, your source in the database/file does not change at all.

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextViewDelegate>
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *aTextView;
```

.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    
    //Your NSTextView
    [aTextView setDelegate:(id)self];
    
    // The Context
    NSString *string = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf1.png lacinia diam, in mattis quam egestas in. Nam gravida dolor adipiscing velit faucibus, vulputate facilisis diam facilisis. Duis id magna nibh. Proin sed turpis aliquet .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf2.png, posuere purus eget, condimentum nulla. Aenean erat odio, suscipit eu aliquet eget, porta in justo. Quisque sed sem dignissim, luctus .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf3.png libero ut, congue libero. Curabitur tristique fermentum risus in fermentum.";
    
    //Regex to find your links .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf2.png
    //You can / should improve Reges patter.
    NSRegularExpression *regexPatternForFullLinks = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\.\\.\\s(.*?\\.png))"
                                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    //Here find all image links and add them into an Array
    NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regexPatternForFullLinks matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    NSMutableArray *links = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in arrayOfAllMatches) {
        [links addObject:[[string substringWithRange:match.range] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".. image:: " withString:@"/"]];
    }

    //Replacing All your links with string: [Image]
    NSString *modifiedString = [regexPatternForFullLinks stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                                             withTemplate:@"[Image]"];
    
    NSRegularExpression *regexPatternReplaceLinksWithIMAGEStr = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[image\\]"
                                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:modifiedString];
    
    //Here,looking for all [Image] strings and add them Link Attribute
    NSArray *arrayOfAllMatchesImageText = [regexPatternReplaceLinksWithIMAGEStr matchesInString:modifiedString
                                                                                        options:0
                                                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedString.length)];
   
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfAllMatchesImageText.count; i++) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *checkingResult = [arrayOfAllMatchesImageText objectAtIndex:i];
        [attrString beginEditing];
        [attrString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[links objectAtIndex:i] range:checkingResult.range];
        [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor greenColor] range:checkingResult.range];
        [attrString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] range:checkingResult.range];
        [attrString endEditing];
    }
    
    //Set NSTextView Storage text...
    [aTextView.textStorage setAttributedString:attrString];
}
```

NSTextViewDelegate: clickedOnLink to handle link clicks.

```
//Open Given Links with Preview App - NSTextViewDelegate 
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView clickedOnLink:(id)link atIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:link withApplication:@"Preview"];
    NSLog(@"%@", link);
    return YES;
}
```

You can see final result on the image. If you want you can give background color to links as well.

[image]

NSTextView settings are important as well.

[image]

## Update:

Just figure out this can be done more elegantly and it is efficient (faster).

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    //Your NSTextView
    [aTextView setDelegate:(id)self];
    
    // The Context
    NSString *string = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf1.png lacinia diam, in mattis quam egestas in. Nam gravida dolor adipiscing velit faucibus, vulputate facilisis diam facilisis. Duis id magna nibh. Proin sed turpis aliquet .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf2.png, posuere purus eget, condimentum nulla. Aenean erat odio, suscipit eu aliquet eget, porta in justo. Quisque sed sem dignissim, luctus .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf3.png libero ut, congue libero. Curabitur tristique fermentum risus in fermentum.";
    
    //Regex to find your links .. image:: images/ssafs/sdfd-sdfsdg-ewfsdf2.png
    //You can / should improve Reges patter.
    NSRegularExpression *regexPatternForFullLinks = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\.\\.\\s(.*?\\.png))"
                                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    //Here find all image links and add them into an Array
    NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regexPatternForFullLinks matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    
    __block NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

    [arrayOfAllMatches enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [arrayOfAllMatches objectAtIndex:idx];
        NSString *linkValue = [[string substringWithRange:match.range] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".. image:: " withString:@"/"];
        NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor greenColor],
                                         NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                         NSLinkAttributeName:linkValue};
        
        NSMutableAttributedString *tempAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"[Image]" attributes:linkAttributes];
        [attrString beginEditing];
        [attrString replaceCharactersInRange:match.range withAttributedString:tempAttrString];
        [attrString endEditing];
    }];
    [aTextView.textStorage setAttributedString:attrString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this sort of thing with `NSTextAttachment` and a custom subclass of `NSTextAttachmentCell`.

Basically create an `NSAttributedString` with your and `NSTextAtachment` that is using your custom `NSTextAttachmentCell`

Source code examples:

from the [BGHUDAppKit framework](https://github.com/binarygod/BGHUDAppKit/blob/Without-Plugin/Framework/NSTokenAttachmentCell.h)

and an [extension of that class](http://edotprintstacktrace.tumblr.com/post/26420382864/nstokenattachmentcell-extention-h-import) for colorization from e.printstacktrace()

**Edit:** it looks like the `NSTokenAttachmentCell` from BGHUD is actually a private apple class. so you could just use that directly if you dont need to be AppStore compliant.