# Set placeholder string for NSTextView without Cocoa binding

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I know "Null Placeholder" for an `NSTextField` or an `NSTextView` can be set in Cocoa binding. Also, for an `NSTextField`, placeholder could be set in Xcode interface builder, or with `aTextField.placeholderString = ...`. If I don't use Cocoa binding, how do I set the placeholder string for an `NSTextView`?

Comment: this post might help if you haven't looked there yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931311/xcode-style-placeholders-in-an-nstextview

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! I thought there would be an easier way, like it is for text fields.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428594/set-the-placeholder-string-for-nstextview

Comment: See me answer for Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43028577/3184888

Answer (score 0):

The placeholderAttributedString property in NSTextView isn't exposed publicly. Thus, you can simply implement it in your own subclass and get the default placeholder behavior:

1 - Create Subclass of NSTextView

```
class CustomTextView: NSTextView {
            var placeholderAttributedString: NSAttributedString?
        }
```

2 - Use in Your Viewcontroller

```
let attributes : [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : NSFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.green]
    yourTextView.placeholderAttributedString =  NSAttributedString(string: "Enter your Name", attributes: attributes)
```