# Set the placeholder string for NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

Is there any way to set the placeholder string for `NSTextView` like that in `NSTextField`? I have checked the property but couldn't find it. I have searched some questions but there isn't a proper explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this answer online.  [Philippe Mougin](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005/Apr/msg00546.html) made this.

```
static NSAttributedString *placeHolderString;

@implementation TextViewWithPlaceHolder

+(void)initialize
{
  static BOOL initialized = NO;
  if (!initialized)
{
     NSColor *txtColor = [NSColor grayColor];
     NSDictionary *txtDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:txtColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
     placeHolderString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is my placeholder text" attributes:txtDict];
 }
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
  [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
  return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
  [super drawRect:rect];
 if ([[self string] isEqualToString:@""] && self != [[self window] firstResponder])
 [placeHolderString drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0,0)];
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
   [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
   return [super resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 4**

As it turns out, there already seems to be a `placeholderAttributedString` property in `NSTextView` that isn't exposed publicly. Thus, you can simply implement it in your own subclass and get the default placeholder behaviour (similar to `NSTextField`).

```
class PlaceholderTextView: NSTextView {
     @objc var placeholderAttributedString: NSAttributedString?
}
```

And if this property will be made available in the future, you only need to use NSTextView instead of this subclass.

Comment: I've filed a radar asking Apple to expose this property http://www.openradar.me/33583675

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I implemented the property in a subclass but it isn't displayed.

Comment: @JanApotheker Yes, it's uncertain whether it's in swift4 or in 10.13. That's not working

Comment: I found you need to use ‘@objc’ to expose the variable in Swift 4

Comment: This displays the text, but it is presented with _some_ vertical offset when compared to setting .textStorage?.setAttributedString() or binding text etc. Values of .baselineOffset and paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore seem to be ignored by whatever renders this string, so this is not a shippable solution for me. I ended up floating an additional non-selectable text view above the other.

Comment: A variation on that solution worked for me (instead of creating a subclass, call `theTextView.perform(Selector(("setPlaceholderAttributedString:")), with: someAttributedString)`) but the `foregroundColor` key of the attributed string is being ignored; the placeholder is getting rendered in black whatever I do. Have others had more success in setting the placeholder color?

Answer (score 7):

Swift 2.0

```
var placeHolderTitleString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Place Holder Value", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.grayColor()])

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    self.needsDisplay = true
    return super.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)

    if (self.string! == "") {
        placeHolderString.drawAtPoint(NSMakePoint(0, 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super helpful, but any ideas as to how to make the placeholder text wrap over multiple lines?

Answer (score 5):

Look for this. It's may be a better approach!

```
final class CustomTextView: NSTextView {

    private var placeholderAttributedString: NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: "Your placeholder string here")
    private var placeholderInsets = NSEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 4.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 4.0)

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        self.needsDisplay = true
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        guard string.isEmpty else { return }
        placeholderAttributedString?.draw(in: dirtyRect.insetBy(placeholderInsets))
    }
}

extension NSRect {
    func insetBy(_ insets: NSEdgeInsets) -> NSRect {
        return insetBy(dx: insets.left + insets.right, dy: insets.top + insets.bottom)
        .applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: insets.left - insets.right, y: insets.top - insets.bottom))
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add these attributes: `[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.placeholderTextColor]`

Comment: I added the following, that can be expanded to properties:

`private var placeholderAttributedString: NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder string", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.placeholderTextColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .light)])`

Answer (score 3):

One of the previous answers suggests subclassing `NSTextView` so that an `@objc var placeholderAttributedString: NSAttributedString?` property can be added to it (which normally isn't publicly exposed).

However, this subclass isn't necessary. Instead, because `NSTextView` conforms to `NSObject`, you can just use `setValue` to set this property, without having to subclass:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = 
  [.foregroundColor: NSColor.secondaryLabelColor]

textView.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: attributes), 
                  forKey: "placeholderAttributedString")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it if you are using storyboards is to place an `NSTextView` and bind its value to a

```
@objc dynamic var myString: String?
```

property in your controller. In the binding inspector you then can set a `Null Placeholder` value and the text view will use that without you having to use any explicitly private API at all.