# How to create float placeholder NSTextfield Cocoa-app Mac OS X (Objective C)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How to create float placeholder NSTextfield Cocoa-app Mac OS X (Objective C)?

I searched about it but only have float placeholder UITextfield IOS.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428594/set-the-placeholder-string-for-nstextview) cover what you're looking to accomplish, or does it have to be an NSTextField?

Comment: @hongtran Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: @dodo, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want an `NSTextField` whose placeholder is a float number, then just create a string with the float and set that as the textfield's `placeholderString`:

```
float f = 0.33;
textField.placeholderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", f];
```